# Trying to display results in table for specific user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to display the billing details for specific users in my admin area. All I want to do is enter a user id into a text field and press submit and the billings that are linked to that user_id will display in the table below. Here's my cac handed effort so far:

admin/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(:action => "show_billings") do %>
<div class="field">
  <p>User ID</p>
  <%= text_field_tag :user_id %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag "Show Billing For This User", :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
<% end %>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">

<thead style="background-color: #efefef">

<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Debits</th>
<th>Credits</th>
<th>Balance</th>
</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<% @billings.each do |billing| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= billing.date %></td>
    <td><%= billing.description %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(billing.debits) %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(billing.credits) %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(billing.balance) %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

admin_controller.rb

```
def show_billings
    billings = Billing.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
    if billings.nil?
      @billings = Billing.where(:user_id => '22')
    else
      @billings = billings
    end
  end
```

I'm getting the following error, which is why I'm trying to make @billings not be nil:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't know if def show_billings is even necessary, still pretty new to rails and everything else I ever do is always wrong so this probably is too, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm do you call the `show_billings` from your `index` action? You show us the `index.html.erb` which is rendered after the `index` action. The form does post to `show_billings`, but it would render `show_billing.html.erb`, normally.

So either, write in your `index.html.erb`, something like `@billings = []` so you won't get an error, and let the `show_billings` render the same view as index. But, I do not even see a real need for a separate action: let the search-form just go to index again? It is the same code anyway.

Comment: yes it's from the index action, sorry for not including that. How do I let the search form just go to index again? I've put redirect_to :action => 'index' in def show_billings but the table doesn't update when I add a user_id into the :user_id field. This is so depressing that displaying a simple table based on a user_id is so hard for me to do. Do we even need the def show_billings or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How does your index action look? If your write `form_tag` without parameters, it will go back to index, of `form_tag :action => index`. So no need for `show_billings`. Ideally, how you would do this: use `admin/users` and click on a user to go to `admin/users/:id` to see the billings of a user. Much closer to the rails-way. On the show-view for a single user I would show a drop-down box with all the users for easy switching. Good luck.

Comment: ok thanks very much for your help, got it working at least, will try those changes you've suggested

Answer (score 1):

```
def show_billings
    if params[:user_id]
      @billings = Billing.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
    else
      @billings = Billing.where(:user_id => '22')
end
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: thanks but that still gives me the same error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Try @billings = Billing.find(:all) to see what's in the array and narrow down to what you need?

Comment: @ billings doesn't get picked up at all if it's in def show_billings, I added @ billings = Billing.all into it and still got the nil:NilClass error (had to add a space after the @ sign to get around the SO comments rule thinking I was trying to notify someone called billings)